# mp4 upload from httppostedfilebase triggers The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, mp4

I really don’t get this and am having little luck in finding any help online.

Please help.

I have a form on my site that allows the user to upload two httppostedfilebase files.

It works fine for anything, word docs, images etc but as soon as I try to upload an mp4 it trigger this message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I am using iis express through visual studio 2015

The signature of my controller is as below :

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Content(string productId, string courseId, string frmChapter, string frmDescription, HttpPostedFileBase frmMainContent, HttpPostedFileBase frmSupportContent)
```

As I said, this is found and triggered for all other file types but mp4, the controller is never hit in this case.

I have added the mime type to web.config

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
</staticContent>
```

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: Have you added MIME Mapping for .mp4 mimeType in your web.config?

Comment: yeah, no joy unfortunately. I have updated the question to show web.config settings as well in case its the way i did these, cant see any problem though.